# Sextante modeler feature selection

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder, intersection, sextante, qgis-modeler

I am trying to select grids (polygon geometry) that intersect with a building layer. I can do it by using "Select by location" tool and then I generate centroids from the selected grids. There is no problem in these steps. Later I generated a model with the sextante modeler but it doesnt work properly. *Select by location* tool dosn't work in sextante modeler. It cannot select features but interesting, I can run this tool perfectly directly from sextante toolbox!

So I need help on how I can extract the grids that intersect with another layer.

**EDIT : Sextante has been renamed to Processing as of QGIS 2.0**

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue in QGIS 2.2, when intersecting shapefiles with prevoiosly selected ones in a simple model.
I've solved with "Intersection" tool as I need to extract table values from spatially selected features.

Answer (score 2):

Using QGIS 2.2 you can use the **v.select** function from GRASS to select features from one layer and how you want to select those features (if they overlap, touch, intersect etc) from another layer:

[image: Processing modeler]

[image: v.select function]

Comment: How is it possible to add the Grass Commands to the Qgis processing modeller?
And especially the v.select tool

Comment: @niels - Go to _Processing_ > _Options and configuration_ > _Providers_ > _GRASS commands_, select to activate it and enter the GRASS directory (eg. _C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3_).